# when writeSatisfiedStatus should be occur

Tags: scorm, scorm2004

If writeSatisfiedStatus is set to true for local objective, in this case, **when** should Objective Satisfied Status be copied from local objective to global objective exactly?

Answer (score 1):

As soon as the learner completes a SCO and the LMS trigers the rollup process which sets the value of satisfied status to either true or false.If this does not happen, the value of satisfied status remains null.

Comment: Could you tell me after which line in the Pseudo Code, please?

Comment: There isn't any reference to global objectives in the Pseudo Code. However, since it is related to the rollup process, your code must handle it emmediately after the SCO is terminated and before the rollup process starts.